# How to install Ubuntu server with custom (non default) LUKS options?

Tags: server, luks, cryptsetup

I'm unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 server with custom LUKS options.

I tried the following:

- Started the live installer
- Went to **help** and selected **Enter shell** (or swtich to a different tty).
- Ran the following commands:

```bsh
# Become root
sudo -i

# Create partitions
sgdisk -n 1:0:+550M -n 2:0:+1G -n 3:0:0 /dev/sda
sgdisk -t 1:ef00 -t 2:8301 -t 3:8301 /dev/sda
sgdisk -c 1:ESP -c 2:boot -c 3:rootfs /dev/sda

# LUKS setup
cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 /dev/sda3

# Map LUKS devices
cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt

# Format
mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n ESP /dev/sda1
mkfs.ext4 -L boot /dev/sda2

# Setup LVM
pvcreate /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt
vgcreate vg01 /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n root vg01
```

- Got back into the live installer.
- Pressed next/enter through the steps until I reached **Storage Configuration**
- Mapped the partitions and logical volumes (everything is showing up fine, detects that `sda3` is encrypted and that it cotains an LVM volume).
- A window will pop up asking if I want commit these changes (yes).

After which the installer starts running but fails right away. I found the following error message(s) in the crash report(s).

Ubuntu 20.04 error:

```
An error occured handling 'dmcrypt-sda3_crypt': RuntimeError - Verifying /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt volume, expecting /dev/sda3, found sda3
```

Tried Ubuntu 18.04 server just to see what would happen.

Ubuntu 18.04 error:

```
An error occured handling 'dmcrypt-sda3_crypt': ValueError - encryption key or keyfile must be specified.
```

Something to note is that all of the above steps work perfectly fine on an Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 desktop installer, which is able to install when LUKS was set up via the terminal.

Further more; when installing via the desktop installer I'm able to launch `ubiquity -b` to omit a bootloader. I found that `subiquity` has a similar option but I was never able to get it to work, running `subiquity --bootloader none` always crashes the installer.